# Jssor Full Width Slider,Hidden Arrow and Bullet

Tags: jssor

How to make **hidden Arrow & Bullet** in first and **show when mouseover it** ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make slider with jssor slider maker, open 'layout' window, switch to 'Bullets' tab, and then change 'Show' property. There are 3 options, 'Never', 'Mouse Over' and 'Always'.

To develop your slider, you can change '$ChanceToShow' option.
http://www.jssor.com/development/reference-options.html